# python pandas upper() not work for string columns

Tags: python, pandas, apply, uppercase, kaggle

Hi I'm working with the Kaggle Titanic data. I use `apply(lambda x: x.upper())` to work on multiple columns, but it doesn't work.

I put the data at my google drive and you can download [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9EHYRPZSyc8OGNWdGxnYTN5YTA/view?usp=sharing).

I test on each column, which is all `object` type (I think it means `str`, correct me if it's wrong please). But some columns report `'float' object has no attribute 'upper'`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', header=0)

train.ix[:,['Name', 'Sex', 'Ticket', 'Cabin', 'Embarked']].dtypes
# Name        object
# Sex         object
# Ticket      object
# Cabin       object
# Embarked    object
# dtype: object

train.ix[:,['Name', 'Sex', 'Ticket', 'Cabin', 'Embarked']].apply(lambda x: x.upper()) 
# not work

# try each column
train.ix[:,'Name'].apply(lambda x: x.upper()) # works
train.ix[:,'Sex'].apply(lambda x: x.upper()) # works
train.ix[:,'Ticket'].apply(lambda x: x.upper()) # works
train.ix[:,'Cabin'].apply(lambda x: x.upper()) # AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'upper'
train.ix[:,'Embarked'].apply(lambda x: x.upper()) # AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

Any help's appreciated. thanks!

Comment: I think it's better to use `str.upper` method for that. May that error comes due to type conversion from `object ` to `float` with your `apply`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your columns `Cabin` and `Embarked` contain `NaN` values which have dtype `np.float`. You could check it with casting type for your apply:

```
In [355]: train.Cabin.apply(lambda x: type(x))[:10]
Out[355]:
0    <class 'float'>
1      <class 'str'>
2    <class 'float'>
3      <class 'str'>
4    <class 'float'>
5    <class 'float'>
6      <class 'str'>
7    <class 'float'>
8    <class 'float'>
9    <class 'float'>
Name: Cabin, dtype: object
```

So you could use [`str.upper`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjt_fjRxu_KAhVmOJoKHSGoCYgQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fversion%2F0.17.1%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.Series.str.upper.html&usg=AFQjCNGLyBOEPrzEzMS5qth-mXOQdLzdrg&bvm=bv.113943164,d.bGs) which handle `NaN` by default. 
Or you could fill your `NaN` values to empty string `''` with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) which has `upper` method and then use your `lambda function:

```
In [363]: train.Cabin.fillna('').apply(lambda x: x.upper)[:5]
Out[363]:
0
1     C85
2
3    C123
4
Name: Cabin, dtype: object

In [365]: train.Cabin.str.upper()[:5]
Out[365]:
0     NaN
1     C85
2     NaN
3    C123
4     NaN
Name: Cabin, dtype: object
```

Or if you'd like to save `NaN` as sting you could fillna with `NaN` string:

```
In [369]: train.Cabin.fillna('NaN').apply(lambda x: x.upper())[:5]
Out[369]:
0     NAN
1     C85
2     NAN
3    C123
4     NAN
Name: Cabin, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing values are present in those columns. These are represented by `numpy.nan` which is a float. If you use `.str.upper()` instead of `.apply(lambda x: x.upper())`, that will recognize this fact and will not produce an error.

Comment: Thanks @Anton Protopopov. Is there nothing like `numpy.str.nan`? Can I coerce it to `object`?